# Provisioning of JAXB in Apache Karaf - fail to resolve javax.xml.namespace

Tags: osgi, apache-karaf

I am trying to deploy a simple feature into a *branded* Karaf 4.0.2 which brings a bundle with a JAXB Specification:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<features name="my-feature" xmlns="http://karaf.apache.org/xmlns/features/v1.3.0">
  <feature name="my-javaee-api" version="6.0-5" install="auto">
    <bundle>mvn:org.apache.geronimo.specs/geronimo-jaxb_2.2_spec/1.0.1</bundle>
  </feature>
</features>
```

It fails with the following error message:

```
2015-12-22 13:38:07,218 | ERROR | a0a-abc5141ad81f | FeatureDeploymentListener        
             | 43 - org.apache.karaf.deployer.features - 4.0.2 | Unable to install features

org.osgi.service.resolver.ResolutionException: Unable to resolve root:
missing requirement [root] osgi.identity; osgi.identity=my-javaee-api; type=karaf.feature; version="[6.0.0.5,6.0.0.5]";
filter:="(&(osgi.identity=my-javaee-api)(type=karaf.feature)(version>=6.0.0.5)(version<=6.0.0.5))"
[
    caused by: Unable to resolve my-javaee-api/6.0.0.5:
    missing requirement [my-javaee-api/6.0.0.5] osgi.identity; osgi.identity=org.apache.geronimo.specs.geronimo-jaxb_2.2_spec;
    type=osgi.bundle; version="[1.0.1,1.0.1]"; resolution:=mandatory
    [
        caused by: Unable to resolve org.apache.geronimo.specs.geronimo-jaxb_2.2_spec/1.0.1:
        missing requirement [org.apache.geronimo.specs.geronimo-jaxb_2.2_spec/1.0.1] osgi.wiring.package;
        filter:="(&(osgi.wiring.package=javax.xml.namespace)(version>=1.0.0))"
    ]
]
```

I wondered how it could miss `javax.xml.namespace` because it's a part of OSGi-Framework. So I checked if that package is really missing:

```
admin@root()>package:exports | grep javax.xml.namespace
javax.xml.namespace | 0.0.0      | 0  | org.eclipse.osgi
```

And voila - here's the root of the problem - the version. For a comparison I checked how it looks on a *stock* karaf:

```
karaf@root()> package:exports | grep javax.xml.namespace
javax.xml.namespace | 0.0.0   | 0  | org.apache.felix.framework
javax.xml.namespace | 1.4.0   | 0  | org.apache.felix.framework
```

It uses Felix and has a proper version 1.4.0. My first thought was that the *branded* karaf uses Equinox as default OSGi-Framework and switching it to Felix would fix that. But a look inside karaf/etc/config.properties has disproved that thought (it looks exactly like *stock*):

```
karaf.framework=felix
karaf.framework.equinox=mvn\:org.eclipse.birt.runtime/org.eclipse.osgi/3.10.2.v20150203-1939
karaf.framework.felix=mvn\:org.apache.felix/org.apache.felix.framework/5.2.0
```

Now I reached an impasse and don't know how to resolve my problem. Any ideas?

Unfortunately I cannot contact people who branded karaf at the moment because they are already at christmas vacation ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure that your custom distribution doesn't change the `config.properties`. 
If it does make sure that the *org.osgi.framework.system.packages.extra*
does contain that version for `javax.xml.namespace;version=1.4,`
Usually if you want to override certain properties for Karaf you can put those changes into the `custom.properties`

Answer (score 0):

The exports from the OSGi Framework are controlled by the configuration properties `org.osgi.framework.system.packages` and `org.osgi.framework.system.packages.extra`. These are appended at runtime to form the *system bundle exports*.

It seems that in your "stock" version of Karaf (not sure what that means but I'll just use your term) somebody has added `javax.xml.namespace;version=1.4.0` to one of those configuration properties. If you are able to do the same in the other version of Karaf then things should work.